# Upper bound on $\frac{e^{-ixu}-1}{u}$

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, he mentions that the function $\varphi(x,u) = \frac{e^{-ixu}-1}{u}$ has the property that $|\varphi(x,u)| \leq |x|$ for all real $u$.  I see where the bound is coming from (the fact that $\varphi$ represents the difference quotient of $e^{-ixu}$ at $u = 0$), but I don't see how to prove the inequality for all $u$.  I've tried working with the limit and power-series definitions of $e$ so far to no avail.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x$ is real, it is enough to notice that

$$ \left| \frac{e^{-ixu} - 1}{u} \right|
= \left| \int_{0}^{x} ie^{-itu} \, dt \right|
\leq \int_{0}^{|x|} dt
= |x|. $$

Alternatively, notice that

$$ \left| \frac{e^{-ixu} - 1}{u} \right|
= \left| \frac{e^{ixu/2} - e^{-ixu/2}}{u} \right|
= \left| \frac{2\sin(xu/2)}{u} \right|. $$

Then utilize the inequality $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ which holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.